# Parsed JSON string not shared between VC

Tags: ios, json

I'm parsing a bunch of strings from my API. One of them is a product ID. I want to use this ID to determine which product was selected so I can parse more details in a detail view controller.

I now have the problem that I parse the ID correctly in the table view (it shows up correctly in the log) but when I push it to the detail view controller I get `(null)` as response from the log there. I don't understand this.

In my table view:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *neuheitenCell = @"neuheitenCell";
    CJHomeTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:neuheitenCell];
    wareID = [[arrayArtikelWareID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"ware_id"];
    //NSLog(@"Selected item with id: %@",sstring);
    return cell;
}

-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CJArtikelDetailViewController *artikelView = [[CJArtikelDetailViewController alloc] init];
    NSString *test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", wareID];
    NSLog(@"Test1: %@", wareID);
    artikelView.wareID = test;
    //NSLog(@"URL1: %@",test);
    return indexPath;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Parse your data like below. I give example in JSON parsing.

```
NSDictionary* dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions  error:&error];
    NSArray* locations = [dictionary objectForKey:@"results"];
    if ([dictionary objectForKey:@"next_page_token"]) 
    {
        nextPageToken = [dictionary objectForKey:@"next_page_token"];    
    }
    else
    {
        nextPageToken = @"";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < [locations count]; i++)
    {

        xmlData =[[LocationModel alloc]init];
        NSDictionary *locationDict = [locations objectAtIndex:i];

        xmlData.name = [locationDict objectForKey:@"name"];
        xmlData.formatted_address = [locationDict objectForKey:@"formatted_address"];

        NSDictionary *geomentry = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
        geomentry = [locationDict objectForKey:@"geometry"];

        NSDictionary *loc = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
        loc = [geomentry objectForKey:@"location"];

        xmlData.lat = [loc objectForKey:@"lat"];
        xmlData.lng = [loc objectForKey:@"lng"];
        xmlData.urlString = [locationDict objectForKey:@"icon"];
        [search_array addObject:xmlData]; 

    }
```

In **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

        if (cell == nil) 
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
        }
        //Model class "LocationModel".
        LocationModel *currentData;

            currentData = [searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

           //Here I display the name. you display ur id. 
           cell.textLabel.text = [currentData name];
        return cell;
    }

then in **didSelectRowAtIndexPath**

    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        LocationModel *currentData = [searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [dataArray addObject:currentData];
         CJArtikelDetailViewController *artikelView = [[CJArtikelDetailViewController alloc] init];
         //Add detailArray in ur class CJArtikelDetailViewController 
         artikelView.detailArray = dataArray;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:artikelView animated:YES];
    }
```

In Ur **detailviewcontroller** display the data by ur model class..

I hope it is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not belong to the JSon parse . The problem is just of passing the String to the another VC .

BeAware of these :

> CJArtikelDetailViewController.h

```
  @property(Strong, nonatomic) NSstring * wareID;
```

In your Current VC , Just pass it from the method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
CJArtikelDetailViewController *artikelView = [[CJArtikelDetailViewController alloc] init];
//    NSString *test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", wareID];

    NSLog(@"Test1: %@", wareID);
    artikelView.wareID = wareID;

  }
```

Comment: This is the console output: 2013-10-24 11:29:22.884 myClassico[3352:70b] ID: (null)
2013-10-24 11:29:22.886 myClassico[3352:70b] Test1: 14356 

"ID:" is the checking NSLog in the detail vc.

Comment: try this ** didSelectRowAtIndexPath** instead of willSelectRowAtIndexPath mt=ethod

Comment: Ok R U using storyboard?

Comment: yes. I have a modal segue from my protoype cell to the detail vc

Comment: Then try this **CJArtikelDetailViewController *artikelView =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC_identifer"];**

Comment: Did you chang the method to this **didSelectRowAtIndexPath**?

Comment: It should work na .. anyhow Can you show me the way you are logging at  CJArtikelDetailViewController..

Comment: NSLog(@"ID: %@", wareID);

Comment: Are U sure about this .. **NSLog(@"Test1: %@", wareID);**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39892/discussion-between-constantin-jacob-and-kumar-kl)